# Pytest - Testing the datatype of columns with a definition file

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, openpyxl

I have a xlsx file with the values:

```html
Product   Person   Quantity 
Egg       Emma       2
milk      Jack       3
```

Note : My code essentially needs to read this file in openpyxl.

While reading this file, I want to check that the column types are correct and if the column have any value which does not match the required type, the column is rejected.

I also created a definition file which have the definition of all the names and datatypes of the columns of the file, like the one below:

```html
{
    "fields": [
        {"name": "Product","type": "string"},
        {"name": "Person","type": "string"},
        {"name": "Quantity", "type": "double"},
    
    ]
}
```

I am trying to write a test in pytest testing that for given name of the column, is the data in the columns if of the correct datatype or not. if not we will reject the whole column and will not pick that up in the output.

I wrote the code like:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook


def test_value_type(data_definition, input_file):
  fields = dataset_definition.fields
  for field in enumerate(fields):
    valuetype = field.type
    valuename = field.name
  
  wb = load_workbook(filename = input_file_name) #Reading the xlsx file as a workbook
  sheet_obj = wb.active
  for column_cell in sheet_obj.iter_cols(1, sheet.max_column):  # iterating through columns
    if column_cell[0].value == valuename:
       for data in column_cell[1:]:    # Reading all the data
             valuedata = data.value   
             assert valuedata.type = valuetype #Checking the type of the data
```

This code is not working as desired. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to by syntax errors in your code;

1. The definition has two parameters **data_definition** & **input_file**. Neither of these are used in the function. And two variables not defined.
   Should **'dataset_definition'** be **'data_definition'** and **'input_file_name'** be **'input_file'** ???
2. Next there is the loop using the enumerate function. This produces a list with two tuples, a count and the field values the later a dictionary.
   'field' has no attribute type or name, if you want those values they are in the list *field[1]['name']* and *field[1]['type']*. Also these are overwritten in the loop so they will only retain the last field values before continuing to the next lines of code. If your trying to test each row in the sheet the rest of the code should be within this loop
3. As mentioned above; there is no variable 'input_file_name'
   .

.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=input_file_name)
```

4. In the next loop
   .

.

```
for column_cell in sheet_obj.iter_cols(1, sheet.max_column):
```

There is no variable 'sheet' should this be 'sheet_obj'???

5. assert is a comparison check so should be double equal sign
   .

.

```
assert valuedata.type == valuetype
```